# What is the efficient way to compare two lists in Java?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, data-structures, collections

I have a program which gets list of java object from db and compares it to the old list that have already been retrieved, and finds the delta (difference) elements in it and returns.
I am wondering if there is best way to do this rather than just using Set methods Union(), Intersection() etc., and avoiding out of memory errors?
Size of the list can be 200k.
I am using Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE version in my project.

```
public class Tester {

    private List<AddressInfo> oldListOfAddresses;

    @Scheduled(cron="0 1 6 * * ?") // 6 AM everyday
    public Map<String, AddressInfo> getCompany() {
        try {
            Map<String, AddressInfo> companyMap = new HashMap<>();
            String sql = "Some sql query which return Address Info.";
            List<AddressInfo> newListOfAddresses = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[0],
                    new FacilityNewMapper());
            if (newListOfAddresses == null || newListOfAddresses.size() = 0) {
                throw new FacilityLookUpException("List of clinic Info from facilities is empty...");
            } else {

                // I have to find the delta of new list and old list here.
                // I need an efficient (Space and Time) way of finding delta.
                List<AddressInfo> deltaList = newListOfAddresses - oldListOfAddresses; //Something like this

                for (AddressInfo comp : deltaList) {
                    if (comp != null) {
                        companyMap.put(comp.getLocationId(), comp);
                    }
                }
                oldListOfAddresses = newListOfAddresses;
            }
            return companyMap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CompanyLookUpException(
                    "List of company addresses is empty..." + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

AddressInfo bean.

```
public class AddressInfo{

    private String locationId;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;

    public String getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }
    public void setLocationId(String locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((locationId == null) ? 0 : locationId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((state == null) ? 0 : state.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((streetName == null) ? 0 : streetName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AddressInfo other = (AddressInfo) obj;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        if (country == null) {
            if (other.country != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
            return false;
        if (locationId == null) {
            if (other.locationId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!locationId.equals(other.locationId))
            return false;
        if (state == null) {
            if (other.state != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!state.equals(other.state))
            return false;
        if (streetName == null) {
            if (other.streetName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!streetName.equals(other.streetName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain *I am wondering if there is best way to do this rather than just using Set methods Union(), Intersection() etc., and avoiding out of memory errors?*

Comment: There is no "best" way. There are very good ways for different scenarios, depending on many factors (sizes of the list, time it takes to retrieve the lists, number of times the comparison has to be performed and so on.)

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  You have not specified what it means to "compare" two lists, and what is meant by the "delta".  FIrst, and MOST IMPORTANT, note that your `AddressInfo` class does not define an `equals()` method.  This means you cannot meaningfully compare two objects of this class, so it is not possible even in principle to do what you are asking.  Assuming you provide an `equals()`, then the question is whether or not the list can contain duplicates (based on `equals()`).  Then, you must tell us if the order of elements matters in the comparison.

Comment: @JimGarrison AddressInfo class implements both `equals()` and `hascode()`, sorry i did not mention it here. And What I actually meant by "delta" is I wanted it get the different elements from the two lists. I have a scheduler running everyday at 6 am which fetches the data from db and stores in the variable `oldListOfAddresses`. So, when the scheduler runs next day I want to get only different elements between yesterdays list and todays list .

Comment: @Gautham.R Is it possible for you to provide the implmentation of  equals() and hascode() here?

Comment: @nagendra547 Added equals() and hashcode() implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Gautham.R. Let me know if below solution is working fine for you!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so (Note: I assume that the order of the list has no importance). For example, the fastest way to do this without using the set is to sort both of the lists which will cost you O(nlogn) and then iterate over them comparing each element and save those that don't have a pair. In case of Set, you will basically iterate over each element and look for it in the second set so the iteration is O(n) and the search is O(1). In the end we have O(nlogn) > O(n) the set wins

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `AddressInfo` implements `equals` and `hashCode` properly, and items in each list are unique, the following function can find the delta in linear time:

```
Set< AddressInfo > findDiff(final List< AddressInfo > newListOfAddresses, final List< AddressInfo > oldListOfAddresses) {
    Map< AddressInfo, Boolean > map = new HashMap<>(newListOfAddresses.size());

    for ( AddressInfo addressInfo : newListOfAddresses ) {
        map.put( addressInfo, TRUE );
    }

    for ( AddressInfo addressInfo : oldListOfAddresses ) {
        map.remove( addressInfo );
    }

    return map.keySet();
}
```

Comment: I agree, I think using Set with equals is good approach to solve the problem.

Comment: You are creating a Map< AddressInfo, Boolean > map. Creating a map for large number of objects might be redundant. Set itself should be good.

Comment: @nagendra547 There is no difference, really; the internal implementation of HashSet is exactly the same.

Comment: The question is currently not answerable because the requirements are insufficient.

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine for creating difference between two list.

Here I am creating a set and adding all elements of newList.
Then whichever elements are part of oldList I am removing them.

```
Set< AddressInfo > findDiffOfTwoList( List< AddressInfo > newList, List< AddressInfo > oldList) {
    Set<AddressInfo> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(newList);
    for(AddressInfo address:oldList){
        set.remove(address);
    }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Why downvoting?